# How can I find an old paper from a Soviet journal of physics?

Tags: particle-physics, specific-reference

I'm looking for the paper of  I. Y. Kobzarev, L. B. Okun and I. Y. Pomeranchuk, Sov. J. Nucl. Phys. 3 (1966) no.6, 837 [Yad. Fiz. 3 (1966) 1154], which I think has the title: *On the possibility of experimental observation of mirror particles*. Where can I find it?

Comment: Can you use the original in Russian, or do you need a translation? I vaguely recall a journal from that era whose content was mostly English translations of Soviet papers. Perhaps the Journal of Theoretical and Experimental Physics (usually abbreviated JTEP).

Comment: Your local research librarian is both friendly and competent. Go have a chat. This particular journal was translated by the AIP (American Institute of Physics), one of many that they translated until ~1992. WorldCat indicates that more than 300 US libraries have copies, so your friendly research librarian won't have to work too hard.

Comment: I was actually looking for an english version of the paper.

Comment: @NikosKoutsopoulos - the Soviet Journal of Nuclear Physics is the version translated into English. The bit in square brackets is the original (Russian) version. That reference style was the standard back in the day. Sadly, it appears that the translated journals have not been converted to electronic formats, perhaps a contractual issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Russian, in a book containing a collection of Pomeranchuk's work: http://elib.biblioatom.ru/text/pomeranchuk_sobranie-trudov_t2_1972/go,284/

Comment: I was actually looking for an english version of the paper, but I'll try to translate it. Thank you.