# On the Terent'ev, M V original article

Tags: wavefunction, specific-reference, mesons

I am in a Phd program and I want to read the Terent'ev, M V original article

"On the structure of the wave functions of mesons considered as bound states of relativistic quarks" or, in russian,

"О структуре волновых функций мезонов как связанных состояний релятивистских кварков [Текст] / М. В. Терентьев. — Москва : ИТЭФ, 1976"
which make the derivation of Melosh rotation to spinor and radial wave function from rest frame to IMF.

But, I search in all place this article and I didn't find it.

Does someone has the acess to this article?

Appreciate.

Comment: Have you contacted a research librarian? See this related comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/726564/how-can-i-find-an-old-paper-from-a-soviet-journal-of-physics#comment1624585_726564

Comment: It ought to be here https://books.google.com.au/books/about/Soviet_Journal_of_Nuclear_Physics.html?id=H7ryAAAAMAAJ but I can't access it

Comment: Thank you. I haven't contacted  research librarian yet, but if I can't find the article, I will.